# Where is the alias for "ll" defined?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, zsh, sh

I often find myself using `ll` which is an alias.

```
$ type ll
ll is an alias for ls -lh
```

I always wondered where this was defined as it works both on `bash`, `zsh` but not on `sh`:

```sh
# THIS IS SH
$ ll
sh: 1: ll: not found
```

Answer (score 12):

In Ubuntu, this alias is defined by default in the `~/.bashrc` file, in mine like this:

```bsh
$ grep "alias ll" ~/.bashrc
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

Another file read by default is the `~/.bash_aliases`. It may not exist until you create it, but it's the recommended way of storing aliases as keeping them in a separate file provides clarity. Your `~/.bashrc` contains the following section, the if expression in which loads this aliases file if it exists:

```bsh
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

As for `zsh` I suppose the alias is defined in the same manner in your `~/.zshrc` file or any file sourced by it. If you use `oh-my-zsh` it may be contained in [`lib/directories.zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/directories.zsh) or [`plugins/common-aliases/common-aliases.plugin.zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/common-aliases/common-aliases.plugin.zsh).

`sh` (= `dash` in Ubuntu) reads only `~/.profile`, which normally doesn't contain any aliases as they are defined shell-specific. In the case of an alias as simple as `alias ll='ls -lh'` however you could go for a definition in `~/.profile`. Further reading: [Is there a “.bashrc” equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3052/246819)

Comment: Most people don't use `dash` much as an interactive shell. But if one does, and wishes to define aliases in `dash`, their definitions should *not* go in `~/.profile`. Like `bash` and other POSIX-compatible shells, `dash` sources `~/.profile` only when run as a login shell--and aliases are not inherited. When an `ENV` environment variable is set, all interactive `dash` shells source the file named in it. Such a file is a good place for aliases. (Setting and exporting `ENV` can be done in `~/.profile`.) See [`man dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/dash.1.html) for details.

Comment: @EliahKagan Please feel free to edit and correct me there!

Answer (score 3):

For zsh, aliases can be added in `.zshrc`. `ll` must have been defined in that file.

You can add an alias in `.zshrc` by editing it with any file editor such as nano. 
For example:

```
alias ll="ls -lh"
```

Comment: If you use the above you can run the following after to make changes take effect : source ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same question on Manjaro Linux, which uses Zsh by default, but I couldn't find any `alias` defined in the usual spots (e.g. `/etc/profile`, `/etc/zsh/zprofile`, `grep -rin alias /etc/*`, `~/.zshrc`, etc.... )

It turns out that Manjaro had installed `oh-my-zsh` under a system-level location: `/usr/share/oh-my-zsh/`

Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322468/7688), I was able to track it down:

```
zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | grep 'll='
```

First line shown in the trace output found it:

```
+/usr/share/oh-my-zsh//lib/directories.zsh:37> alias 'll=ls -lh'
```

Comment: It seems [this file is not packaged for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=directories.zsh), so this answer doesn't apply to Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair.  Yet this is among the first search engine results for the general question, so I figured I would leave an answer here anyway for others (and myself when I forget in the future)

Comment: You can ask and answer on [unix.se] instead.